# How can I use this custom file upload button which is made by vanila js into React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have designed a file upload button by using HTML CSS and JS, I need the same design in React so I need to know how we do the same thing in React?

HTML Code:

```
    <br>

<!-- actual upload which is hidden -->
<input type="file" id="actual-btn" hidden/>

<!-- our custom upload button -->
<label for="actual-btn">Choose File</label>

<!-- name of file chosen -->
<span id="file-chosen">No file chosen</span>
```

CSS Code :

```
label {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  content:"gdg";
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 10px 55px;
}

#file-chosen{
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Javscript code :

```
const actualBtn = document.getElementById('actual-btn');

const fileChosen = document.getElementById('file-chosen');

actualBtn.addEventListener('change', function(){
  fileChosen.textContent = this.files[0].name
})
```

Link  :
https://codepen.io/anishkuls/pen/VwXVJoM

Comment: But... why? Why convert perfectly fine, non-dependent HTML into something as dependent as React? Sigh. I'm also pretty sure you could put this in as-is. Maybe using a styled component (which is another topic altogether) and a little bit of `onChange={}` action in JSX.

Comment: Not need to change but How can i use this this in react ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Upload.js`:

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

const Upload = () => {
    const actualBtnRef = useRef(null);
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("No file chosen");

    return (
        <>
            <input type="file" id="actual-btn" hidden ref={actualBtnRef} onChange={() => setFileName(actualBtnRef.current.files[0].name)} />
            <label htmlFor="actual-btn">Choose File</label>
            <span id="file-chosen">{fileName}</span>
        </>
    );
};

export default Upload;
```